# Visual Studio Profiler Not Sampling My Code

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I was profiling my code last week, but when I started up the profiler today, it's no longer profiling my code. It gives me a warning:

```
Warning 1   DA0008: TotalSamples = 251.00; Only a small number of samples were collected. Consider a longer run or faster sampling rate for more significant results.
```

Last week, I ran my program for 20 seconds to get 4k samples. Today, I ran it for 60 seconds and only got 251. I haven't change the sampling rate. None of my code shows up in any of the samples in the new run while the majority was in my code before. What can I do fix this?

Comment: Isn't the error message self-explanatory?  You have to increase the number of samples by executing a longer run or increasing the sampling rate.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the comment. I've elaborated on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

sampling works by taking periodic stack samples. If you application isn't actually using the CPU it could explain why even though you used it longer it didn't collect more cpu. Is you application blocked on IO or sleeping?